# Make Counter visible in PHP and JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, php, counter

Just looking for a pointer really.

As the title says, I'm trying to make a counter on a page...

I want to initialise it to 0 but be able to add to it or take away with JavaScript, but then read the value in PHP

The reason I'm positing here is that I'm bogged down with session variables/cookies/javascript variables and not sure which is the best way to turn.

I need to be able to 'destroy'/'reset' the counter on page load too.

What's the best thing to look at?

Comment: It gets a lot more confusing when you want to read it via `PHP`. You then need to use `ajax`.

Comment: To explain what I'm doing may help... I've created a div which contains elements pulled from a PHP Databse. This div slides left/right to move the specific item I want in view. I'm trying to make arrows at either side of this box for paging. I just want the arrows to not be in view when at one or other end of the div